# 五笔字型 practicing Apps?

Tags: simplified-characters, learning, input-methods, software

I've recently gotten into the 五笔86 input method and I am wondering if there are any apps on the computer I can use to practice typing so I can get quick with it. I have a Mac and I've looked for a few weeks and failed to find any that are still around and working. Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you can't find is simple:  Wubi is not popular anymore.  It was created specially for a group of elders, your grandparents generation whereas they are good in writing but very bad in standard pronunciation be it Pinyin or 注音 (Zhuyin) and too old to memorize Cangjie (仓颉).  It totally disappeared when hand writing using touch screen came out.  I am 71 now.  I never used it.  With 双拼 and 模糊拼音 functions created, it is even less efficient in input.

Comment: Sorry but I may have caused confusion. I meant 五笔字型 not 五笔画。

Comment: That's professional system designed for professional users exactly because its precision in coding, which means there are no character list to choose after your input, much much faster than Pinyin.  Data input staff like to use it.  Problem is it requires tons of practicing after you learn the basics, similar to 仓颉 (Cangjie, for Traditional characters), but for Simplified.  Not many tricks to play around except practicing, practicing, and more practicing.  No CP value for programmer to design an app for it.

Comment: @JamesLiu刘老师 Once you learn the basic rules of 仓颉, and memorize the few 輔助字形, there is nothing else to learn or memorize. You just type what you see in your head. And, pretty soon, you type solely by muscle memory unless it's a character you've never seen before.

Answer (score 1):

There is a website for Wubi lovers: http://www.52wubi.com/. Maybe it will be useful to you.

Some resources for learning and practicing Wubi:

- [Wubizi](http://www.wubizi.net/) - gives full 汉字 examples for each of the 字根
- [Online IME](https://zaixianwubishuru.51240.com/)
- [清歌输入法](https://apps.apple.com/cn/app/id918951364) IME for Mac
- [WubiLearner](http://www.qinesoft.com/wubi.html) form qinesoft

Comment: Nice find! Lots of flash there, though, so it's going to be partly obsolete in two months...